# How do I get the title attribute of an option tag that I am setting in it using my xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I need to populate the dropdown and onchange of this dropdown I have to set the values in two text fields. I have set the value attribute for option tag and I can use it to put this in my first text box. Now my second textbox should have the value coming from the same xml. I cannot use value attribute twice in xml, so what I did was that I added an title attribute to this option tag. And now I want this title to be put in my second text box, but it doesn't happen. here us what I am suing:

```
$("#country").change(function() {
    $(".firsttextbox").attr("value",$(this).val());  //this works
    $(".secondtextbox").attr("value",$(this).attr('title').val()); //this doesn't work                  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".secondtextbox").attr("value",$(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));
```

Added this line to solution, Example can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/pHpr2/

Using `$(".secondtextbox").attr("value",$(this).attr('title').val());`  fins the `<select title="title">` that is the issue was with you.

Comment: @Mike Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks Sameera, It worked like a charm but juts wondering what was the reason that my code wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by what you're trying to do here. I think, however, that the solution is probably simple.

`attr` retrieves the attribute (or property, in some cases) as a string (or at least it does for the `title` attribute) so there is no need to use `val()` on it – indeed you can't!

```
$(".secondtextbox").attr("value",$(this).attr('title'));
```

Note that it would *probably* suffice simply to use `this.value` and `this.title`, depending on whether the code is in fact XML or if it's HTML.

Comment: it is actually very weird: I already tried what you have I did an alert using this
$(".firsttextbox").attr("value",$(this).val()); //works
$(".secondtextbox").attr("value",$(this).attr('title')); //gives undefined

Comment: I am also of the opinion that option tag cannot have an attribute called title. is that the issue, If so then what would be the alternative

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? Set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net? All elements can have a title attribute/property. It might be better, though, to use a more semantic attribute. Show your HTML: it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(this).attr('title').val()`, try using only `$(this).attr('title')`